# Populate array in parent based on checked inputs in child component via React hooks / functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, callback, use-state, react-functional-component

I have a parent component that renders a list of categories. Each list item contains a child component, Checkbox, which contain a checkbox input.

In the parent component, I need an array containing the ID's of the checkbox inputs that are checked. If a checkbox is unchecked, the ID should be removed from the array.

In the Checkbox component, the `handleChange` function works, but I also need to send the data to the parent somehow. I need some kind of callback function for this, I guess?

How can I access the ID's of the checked inputs in the parent component?

My code so far:

**Parent component:**

```
import {useState} from "react";

import Checkbox from "../functions/Checkbox.js";

function CategoryList() {

    const categories = ['CategoryA','CategoryB', 'CategoryC']

    const [checkedCategories, setCheckedCategories] = useState([]);

    return(
        <ul>
            {categories.map(categories =>
                 <li key={categories.toLowerCase()}>
                     <Checkbox id={categories.toLowerCase()}
                               label={categories}
                     />
                             
                </li>
            )}
        </ul>
    )
}

export default CategoryList;
```

**Child component:**

```
function Checkbox(props) {

   const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

   const checkboxId = props.id;
   const checkboxLabel = props.label;

   const handleChange = () => {

       setChecked(!checked);
       console.log('changed value of checkbox');

   }

    return(
        <label htmlFor={checkboxId} >
            <input type="checkbox"
                   name="category-input"
                   id={checkboxId}
                   onChange={handleChange}
            />
            {checkboxLabel}
        </label>

    );
}

export default Checkbox;
```

Comment: In your parent component, why have you added `export default AllBots();`?

Comment: Add handler method to your parent, pass it down to the child, and notify the changes by raising/ bubbling the event.

Comment: @Inder Oops! It was a typo!

Comment: @Amr That's what I would need some help with. Not sure how to achieve that.

Comment: @mizuki You can look at the answer I've added. A simple function which will return the id of checkbox to parent component which was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just pass the functions to update your checked categories.
Using the lowercase version of your id, it should be something like this:

**Parent component:**

```
function CategoryList() {

  const categories = ['CategoryA','CategoryB', 'CategoryC']
  const [checkedCategories, setCheckedCategories] = useState([]);

  const addToCheckedCategories = id => {
    const updatedCheckedCategories = [...checkedCategories];
    updatedCheckedCategories.push(id);
    setCheckedCategories(updatedCheckedCategories);
  };

  const removeFromCheckedCategories = id => {
    const updatedCheckedCategories = checkedCategories.filter(cat => cat !== id);
    setCheckedCategories(updatedCheckedCategories);
  };

  return(
      <ul>
        {categories.map(categories =>
             <li key={categories.toLowerCase()}>
                 <Checkbox id={categories.toLowerCase()}
                           label={categories}
                           addToCheckedCategories={addToCheckedCategories}
                           removeFromCheckedCategories={removeFromCheckedCategories}
                 />
            </li>
        )}
      </ul>
  );
}
```

**Child component:**

```
function Checkbox(props) {

   const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

   const checkboxId = props.id;
   const checkboxLabel = props.label;
   const addToCheckedCategories = props.addToCheckedCategories;
   const removeFromCheckedCategories = props.removeFromCheckedCategories;

   const handleChange = id => {

       if (checked) {
         removeFromCheckedCategories(id);
       } else {
         addToCheckedCategories(id);
       }
       setChecked(!checked);
       console.log('changed value of checkbox');

   }

    return(
        <label htmlFor={checkboxId} >
            <input type="checkbox"
                   name="category-input"
                   id={checkboxId}
                   onChange={() => handleChange(checkboxId)}
            />
            {checkboxLabel}
        </label>
    );
}

export default Checkbox;
```

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly! I tried logging which category was added/removed and also the array and it does exactly what I want. Thank you very much!

Comment: Follow up question: I need a "clear" button. Clearing the checkedCategories array, and updating the state is no problem - but how do I actually uncheck the checkboxes too?

Comment: Hey! HTML Input checkboxes work with the "checked" property, you could just add a isChecked property in the parent jsx with something like "<Checkbox {...} isChecked={checkedCategories.include(categories)}/>" and in child jsx "<input {...} checked={isChecked}/>" Then to clear all checkboxes you could do setCheckedCategories([]); The state would then be in sync with the checked native HTML property

Answer (score 1):

```js
function CategoryList() {
  const categories = ["CategoryA", "CategoryB", "CategoryC"];

  const [checkedCategories, setCheckedCategories] = useState([]);

  const checkboxChanged = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
  };

  return (
    <ol>
      {categories.map((categories) => (
        <li key={categories.toLowerCase()}>
          <Checkbox
            id={categories.toLowerCase()}
            label={categories}
            checkboxChanged={checkboxChanged}
          />
        </li>
      ))}
    </ol>
  );
}
```

props.checkboxChanged will send id of checkbox to parent component which was changed

```js
function Checkbox(props) {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  const checkboxId = props.id;
  const checkboxLabel = props.label;

  const handleChange = () => {
    setChecked(!checked);
    console.log("changed value of checkbox");

    props.checkboxChanged(checkboxId); // will send id back to parent component
  };

  return (
    <label htmlFor={checkboxId}>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name="category-input"
        id={checkboxId}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      {checkboxLabel}
    </label>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this simple solution! Now I get it! I still need to know if they are checked or not, and store them in an array, but this was really helpful to understand how callbacks work.

Answer (score 1):

I think for this case you need to manipulate objects and not just strings, since you will be storing both a `label` and a `checked` value.

The following code fits better

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import Checkbox from "../functions/Checkbox.js";

function CategoryList() {

    const categories = [{ label: 'CategoryA', checked: false }, { label: 'CategoryB', checked: false }, { label: 'CategoryC', checked: false }];

    const [checkedCategories, setCheckedCategories] = useState([]);
    // Keeps your array of selected categories constantly updated
    useEffect(() => {
        const categoriesFilter = categories.filter(category => category.checked);
        setCheckedCategories(categoriesFilter);
    }, [categories]);

    return (
        <ol>
            {categories.map(category =>
                <li key={category.label.toLowerCase()}>
                    <Checkbox id={category.label.toLowerCase()} data={category} />
                </li>
            )}
        </ol>
    )
}

export default AllBots();
```

```
function Checkbox({ id: checkboxId, data: category }) {

    return (
        <label htmlFor={checkboxId} >
            <input type="checkbox"
                name="category-input"
                id={checkboxId}
                onChange={() => category.checked = !category.checked}
            />
            {category.label}
        </label>
    );
}

export default Checkbox;
```

Comment: You got a good point there - objects would be better than strings. Then I can also manipulate and store the id, instead of using toLowerCase(). I will try your solution as well, thank you so much!

Comment: Exactly, it would be a better idea to incorporate stronger identifiers than just the string, handling these objects will allow you more scalability in case you want to get the `categories` from some services

Comment: Yes, definitely! In this case I actually do get the categories from elsewhere. Along with the list items, each item has an array of categories (strings). I just simplified the code and made a static array instead, as the fetching of categories wasn't relevant for this particular problem.